# OnClientClick Javascript:confirm get value in textbox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, onclick, onclientclick

So I can't seem to find anywhere how to do this. I want to be able to use the value of BuyOutPrice in the text(confirm) box but can't seem to make it work.

More specificly, how am I supposed to write this part:
('Are you sure you want to buy-out for $' + BuyOutPrice + '?')

This was just my closest guess from experience in other programming languages but it appears invalid in JavaScript.

```
var BuyOutPrice = '<%= Content.ComparisonPrice %>';


<asp:ImageButton ID="BuyNowButton" OnClick="BuyNowButton_Click" Style="vertical-align:top;" ImageUrl="Images/btn_buyNow.png" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to buy-out for $' + BuyOutPrice + '?'); BuyNow(); return ValidateBuyNow();" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ComparisonPrice` is a TextBox so try this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ComparisonPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="BuyNowButton" Style="vertical-align:top;" ImageUrl="Images/btn_buyNow.png" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to buy-out for' + momo() + '?'); BuyNow(); return ValidateBuyNow();" />
```

And JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function momo() {
        return document.getElementById('<%= ComparisonPrice.ClientID %>').value
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't straight out work but I will count it as a solution. 

<script>
    function momo() {
        return BuyOutPrice;
    }
</script>

All I needed was to know that a function could be used this way and it worked. Thanks alot!