# how to open an aspx page as popup on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created an aspx page "Analyse.aspx", I want to pass an argument to this page when calling it on a button click of another page say 'Master.aspx' by-
OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('Analyse.aspx?Param=');"

how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

"Could not load type" can happen due to various reasons and not because of popup. Try to call Analyse.aspx directly in your browser and make sure it works. To troubleshoot read [Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'webmarketing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220357/asp-net-error-parser-error-message-could-not-load-type-webmarketing)

UPDATE

Your code is not well formed.

Instead of

```
OnClick="javascript:window.open(Analyse.aspx?Param=""');"
```

must be

```
OnClick="javascript:window.open('Analyse.aspx?Param=');"
```

UPDATE #2

To wire a js code to js onclick event you should use the `OnClientClick()` event

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeDupCheck" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('PieChart.aspx?Param=');" 
Text="De-Duplication Check" Visible="False" />
```

The OnClick() event is used to run a .net code.

UPDATE #3

To add values from asp.net controls you need to inject asp.net code. Read [How to pass a value into a javascript function within an aspx page onClientClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496173/how-to-pass-a-value-into-a-javascript-function-within-an-aspx-page-onclientclick) or [OnClientClick Javascript:confirm get value in textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407975/onclientclick-javascriptconfirm-get-value-in-textbox)

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDeDupCheck" runat="server" 
OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('PieChart.aspx?Param=<%=txt1.ClientID%>');" 
Text="De-Duplication Check" Visible="False" />
```

Comment: I have fixed the last issue, now a new error is coming as shown above in the edited problem. please help I that.

Comment: Now it is giving an error-"Too many characters in character literal". What it is referring to?. is the 'Param' essential to be given and if yes then I think 'Analyse.aspx?Param=' is incomplete. what is the the right thing?

Comment: Do you have punctuation marks ' ' around your string?

Comment: no, I have used as you suggested as -"      OnClick="javascript:window.open('Analyse.aspx?Param=');"       ".

Comment: Please share a little more code around OnClick. The error about "Too many characters" is usually occur when using ' ' in the code behind.

Comment: my control is-
<asp:Button ID="btnDeDupCheck" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:window.open('PieChart.aspx?Param=');" Text="De-Duplication Check" Visible="False" />

Answer (score -1):

I finally got the it,successful executed code-
OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('Analyse.aspx?Param=');"
but my new query is how to pass parameter from current page to this new page 'Analyse.aspx',
say my parameter is -  "txtPwd.text"
and how to catch the argument on pageload of Analyse.aspx

Comment: Remove this answer as it does not answer anything and either create new question or edit your original message.

Comment: I have changed the question, please refer it